# Why when using HttpClient and sending http request using SendAsync the application is hanging for almost 7 seconds?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is in github and including also the usage code in form1: https://github.com/chocolade1972/Downloading-Test

The problem is once I click the button to start downloading the application not freezing but the actual download does not start yet and it's waiting almost 7 seconds before starting to download the first file and then when the first file finished downloading it's waiting again more or less 7 seconds before start downloading the next file and so on.

The download itself is working, but the delay between each download is something I can't figure out why it happens and how to fix it.

I used a break point and followed the code and found that when it's getting to this line and executing this line then the delay happens.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
```

The method code:

```
public async Task StartDownload(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var requestMessage = _requestMessageBuilder.Invoke();

    long? totalFileSize = null; // Calculate or obtain the total file size

    if (totalFileSize.HasValue && totalFileSize <= 100 * 1024 * 1024)
    {
        if (requestMessage != null && requestMessage.RequestUri != null)
        {
            var streamingDownload = new StreamingDownloadWithProgress(_httpClient, _destinationFilePath);
            streamingDownload.ProgressChanged += (total, downloaded, progress) => ReportProgress(total, downloaded, progress);
            await streamingDownload.StartDownload(requestMessage.RequestUri, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle the case where requestMessage or its RequestUri is null
            // You might want to log a warning or throw an exception
        }
    }
    else
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
        await DownloadAsync(response, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I can put here the whole class but it's too much code to put here at once.

I put the code here then:  https://pastebin.com/rQmp3L5J

Comment: Did you measure the responsiveness of the server with another way to access it? Browser? Some tool? Do you see the same start-delay there? If you do, it's the server, not your code.

Comment: @Fildor yes,  i tried the same link in my application also in edge web browser and the response for start downloading was at once without any delay.  the delay is in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly this line:

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
```

is for getting file size, right?

If no, then probably this answer won't help.

If yes then you're doing it in the wrong way. the point is `requestMessage` is `GET` method which means **it will download the file first** and then return the response headers.

Best solution is using `HEAD` method for getting file size (which is the `Content-Length` in the headers) so you can change this method to fix that:

```cs
 private static Func<HttpRequestMessage> GetDefaultRequestBuilder(string downloadPath)
    {
       return () => new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.HEAD, downloadPath);
    }
```

Just to mention, some webservers disable the `Head` HTTP method, so need to care about it as well.